# Writing a scenario

Tags: technique, self-publishing

I have always wanted to write a scenario for a series that could be translated into several episodes, but I didn't know where to start or how should a scenario look like.
My question is: does any one know the right tools in order to write a scenario?

Comment: You'll have to define "scenario" in this context.

Comment: A series of what? Who is your audience -- you or someone who is commissioning? What do you mean by tools?

Comment: Scenario as in script, right?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to write [a film treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_treatment). This is a recognized approach for creating and marketing story ideas to the film and television industry. Typically, you start out by creating and organizing the story elements using index cards (or similar software). Or, if you are working on an adaptation, you start from a short story or news article. Then, you write a treatment, which is:

"a piece of prose, typically the step between scene cards (index cards) and the first draft of a screenplay for a motion picture, television program, or radio play. It is generally longer and more detailed than an outline (or one-page synopsis), and it may include details of directorial style that an outline omits. Treatments read like a short story, but are told in the present tense and describe events as they happen."[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_treatment)

If this is what you're looking for, I searching your library or book vendor for titles on "film treatments".